# Redirecting Primary domain to a Wordpress Installation in the Subdirectory without changing URL

Tags: domain

I have a primary domain at www.example.com. We installed Wordpress at www.example.com/wp.

When we set up the redirect from www.example.com to www.example.com/wp, it works, but we would like to hide the /wp from the URL.

I have tried to edit the .htaccess and remove the original redirect as recommended by Wordpress, but that resulted in a 403 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!